# iPhone adhoc distribution without entitlements

Tags: iphone, adhoc

I'm trying to make an ad-hoc distribution of our app for sending to another company for beta testing. They are asking me to remove the Entitlements.plist file from my project.

As far as I know that file is absolutely required and I get a code signing error if it's not there.

Is there a way to build an iPhone app for distribution without an Entitlements file?

Comment: That's bizarre.  Why would they care about the Entitlements.plist file?  It has no proprietary information in it and its only purpose is to enable ad-hoc distribution.

Comment: Somehow they thought that building my project without it would fix this ad-hoc build. But if you're right then I'm even more at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the entitlements.plist file is essential. Your ad-hoc distribution will fail without it. But it seems it is unnecessary in distribution build.

Answer (score 0):

Out on a limb: What they may actually be seeing is a problem between their OS and .mobileprovision file which throws an error referring to entitlements. Are they seeing an error about the entitlements file when they try to sync the app with the phone?

I have seen this recently and am not fully sure of the answer. I think that on some Macs (i'm thinking 10.5) iTunes is not associated with the .mobileprovision file. I have seen this twice now. The first time the answer was to have the person do an "Open With" on the .mobileprovison file and choose "Other" and then select iTunes. That did the trick.

I have been unable to find an answer to this latest event from tonight. However this person has 10.5 and also XCODE.

I'm still working on this but if you have not found an answer yet, maybe the "Open With" might help.

Good luck.

Update:
I just now go the second issue solved. Email can corrupt the .mobileprovision file. I finally zipped the .mobileprovision file and sent it to those having trouble and it solved the 2nd version of the issue!